# What is the best way to use layers and partial rendering in iOS for speed

Tags: ios, uiview, path, calayer, cashapelayer

I'm working on a graphing application which I wrote using Core Graphics. I have a buffer which accumulates data, and I render it on the screen.  It's super slow and I want to avoid going to openGL if possible.  According to the profiler, drawing my graph data is what's killing me (which consists of a number of points which are converted to a path, followed by the calls AddPath, DrawPath)..

This is what I want to do, my question is how to best implement it using layers / views / etc..

I have a grid and some text.  I want this to be rendered in a CALayer (or some other layer/view?) and only update when required (the graph is rescaled).

Only a portion of the data needs to be refreshed.  I want to take the previous screen buffer, erase a rectangle's worth of data (or cover it with a white box) and then draw only the portion of the graphs that have changed.

I then want to merge the background layer with the foreground graphs to generate the composite image.  This requires the graph layer to have a transparent background so as not to obscure the grid.

I've looked at using CAlayer as a sublayer, but it doesn't seem to provide a simple way to draw a line.  CAShapeLayer seems a bit better, but it looks like it can only draw a single line.  I want the grid to be composed of multiple lines.

What's the best approach and combination of objects to allow me to do this?

Thanks,
Reza

Comment: How do you know which section of the graph will change during rescale (is it basically a throw everything away and redraw only a section)? And are you continuously adding more points which extend the graph (and currently redrawing the entire graph each time)?

Comment: for rescale, i will redraw everything.  when new data comes in, it is drawn from left to right, when it reaches the right edge then i start over at the left.  so i only need to update a small section of the screen where the new data is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a `CGLayerRef` that was used for drawing the path into. For each new point I'd draw just the new segment. When the graph got to full width I'd create a new `CGLayerRef` and start drawing the new line segments into that.

What happens to the previous layer as it's drawn over by the new layer depends on how your graph is displayed, but you could clear the section which is now underneath the new layer (using `CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);`) or you could choose to blend them together in some other way.

Drawing the layers each time you make a change to the lines they contain is relatively cheap compared to drawing all of the line segments themselves.

Technically, there would also be `CALayer`s used to manage the drawing of the `CGLayerRef`s to the screen (via the delegate relationship `drawLayer:inContext:`), but all of the line drawing is done using the `CGLayerRef`s context and then the `CGLayerRef` is drawn as a whole into the `CALayer`s context (`CGContextDrawLayerInRect(context, frame, backingCGLayer);`).